# Broken RenderPartial with MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've come to an MVC3 project I wrote just a week ago which has stopped working and is throwing the following error:

`Error  10
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string)' and 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string)`'

What is the reason for this? I haven't changed anything in project recently for it to bork. The code I call it in looks like this:

```
<div class="page-body">
    @if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.ErrorMessage)) {
        // Output error message
        Html.Raw(ViewBag.ErrorMessage);
    } else {
        // Render upload form
        Html.RenderPartial("_UploadForm");
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing @ symbols front of your Html.Raw because teh method reutrns a string back hence requires the @symbol

> **For your knowledge taken from MSDN :** The Razor syntax @ operator
>   HTML-encodes text before rendering it to the HTTP response. This
>   causes the text to be displayed as regular text in the web page
>   instead of being interpreted as HTML markup.

Please use it this way

```
<div class="page-body">
    @if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.ErrorMessage)) {
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ErrorMessage);
    } else {
        // Render upload form
        Html.RenderPartial("_UploadForm");
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Gah so simple after staring at it for quite some time, thanks!